# Cannot remote access to MongoDB Atlas from anywhere except my house

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a full stack MERN app.

When I am working on the project from my home, everything works fine.

However, as soon as I change my location to somewhere else(different IP adress) like a cafe, the connection to mongoDB fails..

This is what I have tried:

1,Add the IP address of the new location to the network access of my DB => doesn’t work

2, Add “allow access from anywhere” to the network access => doesn’t work

3, disabled firewall on my MacBookAir => doesn’t work

4, create a new user in the DB and try to use the new user login => doesn’t work

5, I am not using any proxy.

I am using macOS BigSur(version 11.5.2)

this is my index.js file

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const motorRoute = require("./routes/motors");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
var cors = require("cors");
dotenv.config();

//connect to the DB here
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  () => {
    console.log("connected to MongoDB");
  }
);

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/images/")));

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));
// app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (req.path == "/api/upload") {
      console.log("yes the path is /api/upload");
      cb(null, "public/images/posts/");
    }
    if (req.path == "/api/upload/profile") {
      console.log("yes the path is /api/upload/profile");
      cb(null, "public/images/person/");
    }
    
    // cb(null, "public/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
 
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

//upload post from share
const upload = multer({ storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
    return res.status(200).json("File uploaded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
  
    console.log(error);
  }
});
///upload profile picture
const upload2 = multer({ storage });
app.post("/api/upload/profile", upload2.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  try {
  
    return res.status(200).json("File uploaded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
   
    console.log(error);
  }
});

//get all the users
app.get("/api/allusers", (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("debug: I will try to get all the users");
 
    return res.status(200).json(" will return users here");
  } catch (error) {
   
    console.log(error);
  }
});
//set some routes in here
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/motors", motorRoute);



app.listen(8800, () => {
  console.log("Backend server is running");
});
```

Please let me know if you need more information about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to connect from whitelisted IPs.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/